# How to merge two hands of cards together in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, syntax, enums, operators, definition

I'm still very new to Haskell, and I'm curious as to how I would merge two `Hand`'s together, so that, the first hand is placed on top of the second hand. I want it to be an infix operator, namely (<+). Here's some code to  assist you. I keep getting an error saying "The type signature for ‘<+’ lacks an accompanying binding".

```
data Rank = Numeric Integer | Jack | Queen | King | Ace

data Suit = Hearts | Spades | Diamonds | Clubs

data Card = Card Rank Suit

data Hand = Empty | Add Card Hand

(<+) :: Hand -> Hand -> Hand
h1 (<+) h2 = undefined
```

Many thanks in advance for any advice given.

Comment: Hint: what should happen for two `Empty`s, for an `Empty` and an `Add x y`, with an `Add x y` and an `Empty`, and with `Add x y` and `Add z t`?

Comment: `Hand` is a list equivalent and you're trying to define append....

Comment: @karakfa yes, that is correct

Comment: @Alex: I don't see why you do not use `type Hand = [Card]`. Then you do not need to implement an append function in the first place.

Comment: as a suggestion aside from the question. Derive your types so you can print them in the console `data YourTypeName = Constructor1 | Constructor2 |.... deriving(Eq, Show)`

Comment: Don't edit a question that has already been answered.

Comment: @chepner my apologies, but the answer didn't answer the question due to my lack of clarity in the question given.

Comment: Then ask a new question. You specifically asked about the type-signature error, which my answer addressed. How to then define `(<+)` is a separate question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The definition should either be

```
h1 <+ h2 = undefined
```

or

```
(<+) h1 h2 = undefined
```

You are currently trying to use a function name as an infix operator.