# How can I fuse two enums of the same type in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, enums, haskell-platform

I'm still very new to Haskell, and I'm curious as to how I would merge two `Hand`'s together, so that, the first hand is placed on top of the second hand. I want it to be an infix operator, namely (<+). Here's some code to  assist you. Essentially, what I'm saying is that I need help to "append" the two hands in some way.

```
data Rank = Numeric Integer | Jack | Queen | King | Ace
            deriving (Eq, Show)

data Suit = Hearts | Spades | Diamonds | Clubs
            deriving (Eq, Show)

data Card = Card Rank Suit
            deriving (Eq, Show)

data Hand = Empty | Add Card Hand
            deriving (Eq, Show)

(<+) :: Hand -> Hand -> Hand
(<+) Empty Empty = Empty
(<+) h Empty     = h
(<+) Empty h     = h
(<+) h1 h2       = h1 ++ h2
```

So far I've tried `merge`, `append`, `mappend`, and `++` as seen above.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge two hands of cards together in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58938019/how-to-merge-two-hands-of-cards-together-in-haskell)

Comment: @JosephSible sorry, that was actually a previous question I asked, similar, but not the same.

Comment: @MichaelLitchard updated

Comment: @Alex when I posted that, it was an exact duplicate. Now you've edited it into something entirely different.

Comment: @JosephSible yeah my apologies, I forgot to update it, but thank you for your prudence

Comment: @JosephSible I can vouch that this is the question Alex meant to ask, since I'm the one who told him to post a new question.

Comment: Why exactly you make a `Hand` a recursive type instead of a `List` i.e. `type Hand = [Card]` or another similar predefined type like Sequence or Array? Now you have to think for all kinds of functions and class instances of it..? How about folding a `Hand`..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pattern match on one of the non-empty hands so that you can access the cards in it.

```
(<+) :: Hand -> Hand -> Hand
Empty <+ h = h
h <+ Empty = h
(Add c rest1) <+ h = Add c (rest1 <+ h)
```

Strictly speaking,  you don't need `h <+ Empty = h`, since the third rule can rebuild the hand once you reach `Empty <+ h`. But the second rule saves some computation.

You can't use `++` et al. because none of them are defined for `Hand`. However, as was pointed out in a comment on your previous question, all `Hand` does is re-implement the built-in list type. You can take advantage of that by defining a new type.

```
newtype Hand = Hand [Card]
```

Then

```
(<+) :: Hand -> Hand -> Hand
(Hand h1) <+ (Hand h2) = Hand (h1 ++ h2)
```